# how to run samples of wso2 identification server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I try to download sample code from http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk06/products/is/4.7.0/modules/samples. 
But the POM file has reference to ..\pom.xml. 
There is no pom file under http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk06/products/is//4.7.0/modules.

Can somebody introduce how to download and run samples?
I really think http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Consuming+SCIM+Rest+Endpoints is too simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the source of WSO2IS 4.7.0 which has not been released. Then latest version is 4.6.0 and SCIM sample source of it can be found at [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk06/products/is/4.6.0/modules/samples/scim/)

Comment: is it possible you provide some WSO2IS 4.7.0 alpha or RC download? otherwise I will try to build from source.. (not very successful yet, missing some artifacts at the repo...) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

seems a lot of work, after I checkout code, I find the folder structure required in build.xml is not like the real folder structure. 
I need to manually create folder under identification server, and add files which are checked out from svn.

Answer (score 0):

yes, after switching to 4.6, and download code, compile them, then copy files into run time environment, I can run sample code now. 
Thanks for the help.